# How to call a method from one class to another class when both are TestNG classes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, test-automation-framework, testng

I have 2 TestNG classes which are:

1. **ProductCanvas**

   ```
   package objectRepo;

   import java.util.List;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class ProductCanvas {
       private WebDriver driver;
       private By product = By.tagName("app-product-item");
       private By productName = By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']");
       private By addToCartButton = By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Add to Cart')]");
       private By productImage = By.xpath("//img[@itemprop='image']");
       private By favIcon = By.cssSelector(".fa.fa-heart");
       private By price = By.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='price']"); 

       public ProductCanvas(WebDriver driver) {
           this.driver = driver;
       }

       public WebElement getProduct() {
           return driver.findElement(product);
       }

       public WebElement getProductName() {
           return driver.findElement(productName);
       }

       public List<WebElement> getProductNames() {
           return driver.findElements(productName);   
       }

       public WebElement getAddToCartButton() {
           return driver.findElement(addToCartButton);
       }

       public List<WebElement> getAddToCartButtons() {
           return driver.findElements(addToCartButton);   
       }

       public WebElement getProductImage() {
           return driver.findElement(productImage);
       }

       public WebElement getFavIcon() {
           return driver.findElement(favIcon);
       }

       public List<WebElement> getfavIcons() {
           return driver.findElements(favIcon);   
       }

       public WebElement getPrice() {
           return driver.findElement(price);
       }

       public List<WebElement> getPrices() {
           return driver.findElements(price);   
       }
   }
   ```
2. **ProductTC**

   ```
   package productTestCases;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
   import objectRepo.Cart;
   import objectRepo.ProductCanvas;

   public class ProductTC {
       private WebDriver driver;
       private String baseUrl = "http://test.com";

       public ProductTC(WebDriver driver) {
           this.driver = driver;
       }

       @BeforeTest
       public void openBrowser() {
           System.setProperty("driver.webdriver.chrome", "C://chromedriver.exe");
           driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get(baseUrl);
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }

       @Test
       public void test1() {
           ProductCanvas pc = new ProductCanvas(driver);
           int count = pc.getPrices().size();
           System.out.println(count);
       }
   }
   ```

When I try to run ProductTC, nothing happens and this is displayed on console:

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

But when I remove the ProductTC's constructor it runs. 
How would I be able to run ProductTC without removing the constructor given that another class below would need to call its method?

3. **LandingPageTestCases**

   ```
   package productTestCases;

   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   import objectRepo.Cart;

   public class LandingPageTestCases {
       private WebDriver driver;
       private String baseUrl = "http://test.com";

       public LandingPageTestCases(WebDriver driver) {
           this.driver = driver;
       }

       @BeforeTest
       public void openBrowser() {
           System.setProperty("driver.wedriver.chrome", "C://chromedriver.exe");
           driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get(baseUrl);
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }

       @Test
       public void addProductsToCart() throws InterruptedException {
           ProductTC ptc = new ProductTC(driver);
           ptc.test1();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the common code into a separate helper class (not a test class). Then have both test classes instantiate the helper and call its method to do the common task.

You could extract the common code into a base class, but base classes tend to become tangled or bloated as different subclasses demand different behavior from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be instead of trying to use the `ProductTC` class in `LandingPageTestCases` class.

You can just directly use the page object methods of `ProductCanvas` in the `LandingPageTestCases` class by creating its instance as you have done above:

```
class LandingPageTestCases {
...
@BeforeTest
...

    @Test
    public void addProductsToCart() throws InterruptedException {
      ProductCanvas pc = new ProductCanvas(driver);
      int count = pc.getPrices().size();
      System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

By doing such way you would also avoid any dependency between your test cases.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid writing the same code again in another method.

Comment: I think the basic navigation (to a page) will be repeated in the each test method